# I have opened an account with a Neobank Yuh. I'm totally confused why I don't have a username and password, there is also no 2FA

Tags: banking, online-banking, security, switzerland

In less than 1 hour I was able to open an account with [Yuh](https://www.yuh.com/en). The process worked very well, only small bugs.

I could not find a web UI for Yuh. On the iPhone Yuh app, I log in with FaceID. Am totally confused why I don't have/need a username and password. This is the first account where I don't have username and password. Maybe a technical question, but I don't understand how this works?

What happens if my iPhone is lost, my AppleID is banned or I decide to use Google/Android garden?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is not about personal finances, but about IT security. That means it belongs to https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Seems like a question you should be asking your bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face ID *is* a user identity confirmation, effectively equivalent to userID plus password.

It's not a very secure one, and as you note it's dependent upon particular hardware/software, and it would be better as one part of a multifactor authentication... but if you choose to rely on it, that's your choice.

If you don't like doing so, ask the bank for alternatives or find an alternative bank.